# PHP curl not handling images properly

Tags: php, curl, gd, libcurl

I have an internal proxy that fetches data from my own server and displays to the client. I wanted to keep the proxy side code minimal, and thought that just sending the data got from the content server as-it-is to the client will work for all media types. It is working fine for HTML/TEXT code. However, not for images. I am unable to understand why.

Here is the proxy side code:

```
$curl_url="http//myserver.com/someimage.jpg";
//Open connection
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_COOKIE,session_name()."=".session_id().";");
//Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
/// curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_request_headers);
/// Above is actually uncommented but omitting details for brevity. They are just 
/// HTTP headers passed by the client
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "identity");

//Execute post
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);

//Close connection
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $result;
```

Why does above not display images correctly?  (Is it not possible to make the proxy like a dummy bridge - that it does not interpret the result sent by the server but just pass it on and still make it work for all content/media types?). Can someone suggest the cleanest solution?

---

Notes:

1) The content server handles all files through a php script, and is correctly passing the header using 
 `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

It works fine if I access directly from the server. However from the proxy, it does not work (browser displays binary data).

2) 
I don't understand CURLOPT_HEADER very well either.

If I use

`curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`

browser tries to download gzipped data (for text as well as images).

If I use

`curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`

browser displays text/images correctly, but not image data.

---

These are the response headers shown by Google Chrome, when I access the image in the browser via the proxy (direct link).

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:2576
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 29 Nov 2010 18:03:52 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5
```

---

The response headers when I access image directly on the content server:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:3669
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 29 Nov 2010 18:07:25 GMT
ETag:"1802b6-e55-49633c9623e40"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=96
Last-Modified:Mon, 29 Nov 2010 16:44:33 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
```

I have a feeling this is due to the Content-type being GZIP via the proxy. Can someone please help me understand this:  Aren't images GZIPPed by apache by default? (I agree savings might be less).  If not, then is  CURL (the proxy) Gzipping the data? Shouldn't CURLOPT_ENCODING, "identity" prevent it? How do I fix?

Comment: Spencer's continued comments helped me solve the problem. With CURLOPT_HEADER=1, I was not parsing the headers correctly and with CURLOPT_HEADER=0, I was not trying to give the correct header back to the client even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the proper headers using `header` to tell the browser the correct content-type, otherwise it assumes it is just plaintext.

Comment: My server is passing the header using header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  (the image is served via PHP on the server). It works fine if I access directly from the server. However, through the above proxy, it doesn't work. Also please see my added note in the ques.

Comment: Ok, so, how is this set up? I'm assuming your HTML output has something like `<img src="someimage_proxy.php" />`, or what?

Comment: I am accessing someimage_proxy.php directly in the browser.

Comment: And is it displaying the binary output, or just a blank page?
*Edit* Whoops, just saw that you already mentioned that. I'm not really sure, but use the Net panel in Firebug to see the headers that are being sent/received.

Comment: Okay, let me debug the headers. Btw, can you suggest what should be the right setting for CURLOPT_HEADER (1 or 0)?

Comment: `CURLOPT_HEADER` controls whether the response headers are included in `$result`. Setting this to 1 would probably make your life a bit easier, as you wouldn't have to worry about sending the right Content-type on your own.

Comment: added the headers. any clue? is it due to gzip encoding?

Comment: It might be, I don't know how your server is specifically set up.

Comment: @JP19 Ok, your proxy response headers have "Content-type: text/html". That's the problem. It may be that Apache's MIME types are screwed up, I'm not too knowledgeable about that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You're getting the image as a string via Curl, so when you echo $result, you're printing the data for the image as opposed to rendering `<img src="..." />`

Comment: If I were to access http//myserver.com/someimage.jpg directly in the browser, my server would give back binary data to the browser (no <img src....>). (Actually, on encountering <img src..>, the browser would make the request for the file).